# Programmatically activate users

Tags: 7, users, rules

I have a custom module that allows administrator users to review users, and then approve their registration. I can't figure out how to programmatically trigger the 'approve' process.

Changing their role, or doing a regular `user_save()` with the new status doesn't seem to trigger rules associated with activating the user.

I'm sure there's a simple function for this, but I can't find it.